# Kähler differential and ramification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have proved that the annihilator of Kähler differential is related with branching locus of homomorphism of rings. Now I want to use this to deduce the criterion that for number field K, all ramified prime numbers are divisors of the discriminant. Denote ann $\Omega_{B/A}$ by $D_{B/A}$. Usual treatment prove this is the different, for example in Neukirch book. But I want to avoid this, to **directly show $N(D_{B/A})=d_K$, where N is the norm.** Following is my attempt.

Choose an integral basis $\alpha_i$, and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is integral over ℤ. Let A be the transformation matrix from the $ \mathbb{Q}$ basis $1, \alpha, \cdots , \alpha^{n-1}$ to $\alpha_i$, by linear algebra we have $|d_K|= (\det A)^2 |f’(\alpha)|.$ (The discriminant of $1, \alpha, \cdots , \alpha^{n-1}$ just has absolute value $f’(\alpha)$.)

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}, B= \mathbb{Z}[\alpha],C =O_K.$ By $N(D_{C/A})= N(D_{C/B}) N(D_{B/A})$, and $|N(D_{B/A})|=|f’(\alpha)|$, **we only need to show $|N(D_{C/B})|=  (\det A)^2  $. This is my question.** C/B is a torsion finite abelian group, hence $N(D_{C/B})$ should be the minimal torsion. I think the rest is some linear algebra work, but I can’t see the point.

Comment: there is a suggested proof in Neukirch, "Algebraic number theory" - have you studied this proof and compared?

Comment: @hm2020 Yes, and what I’m doing is to try to avoid the definition of difference there. But I think that isn’t good idea now.